# how to mock the moving parts - snapshot test - react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I am doing snapshot testing and getting false fails due to the different time's and id's that are randomly generated.
so, how do I ignore those parts in the test or mock them
Here are a few errors given by the test:

```
<span>
    -           Today at 10:21 AM
    +           Today at 12:34 PM
              </span>
```

and

```
<input
                disabled={false}
    -           id="undefined-Search-undefined-24783"
    +           id="undefined-Search-undefined-63537"
                onBlur={[Function]}
                onChange={[Function]}
                onFocus={[Function]}
```

This is the part in the code, which outputs the time

```
 <p style={profileStyle}>
              <span>
                {moment().
                  subtract(20, 'm').
                  calendar()}
              </span>
```

and

```
<span>{moment('1/12/14').calendar()}</span>
```

and this one outputs the id's generated randomly

```
<TextField
              hintText="Search"
              fullWidth
            />
```

here's my test code

```
test('renders correctly', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <CheckinHistory/></MuiThemeProvider>);
  const tree = component.toJSON();

  console.log('tree is : ', tree);
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I have tried to mock using this

```
  moment().subtract(20, 'm').calendar() = jest.fn()
```

but the linter gives error and it doesnt seem correct too.
so, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is where separation of concerns comes in handy.

If you make your UI components only receive calculation results in props, and use a parent component to do the calculations, you can do the snapshot tests on the UI components (which will stop changing), and test the functions separately.

Comment: umm, well. any other ideas??

Comment: If you start mocking all of the moving parts, you'll get a pretty brittle test, and also it will be a lot more complicated to write. Separating things out now will make your life much easier.

Comment: ok, and what about the random id's that TextField generates. it is a material ui thing and I cant separate that from the component.
what about that?

Comment: I'd check for an option to override the ID, and if that's impossible, wrap the text field with my own component, and pass it as a child. You can then replace that with a simple hand-rolled mock in the test.

Comment: so, how does one do that?
the mocking part I mean.
I dont quite get what you meant by wrap text field with own component and pass it as a child.
could you give a code example, please?

Comment: Actually, wrapping might be unnecessary if your component becomes a [HoC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). You just pass a hard coded child in the test. Also, the [docs for material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field) say that you can provide the id for TextField. So that would probably make things easier.